# How can I add grid lines to this CSS Grid layout?

Tags: css-grid

I am trying to create a day by day calendar, like demonstrated.

However I'd like to have a continuous dotted line across the grid rows.  The only options I've found have not worked for this particular layout, due to the use of grid-row-start.

I've tried a few approaches by adding a grid-gap and changing background colour, but it doesn't work with this approach.

I am wondering if I am going down the wrong path with this layout, should I try another way?

```css
:root {
  --numHours: 10;
  --timeHeight: 50px;
  --calBgColor: #fff1f8;
  --eventBorderColor: #f2d3d8;
  --eventColor1: #ffd6d1;
  --eventColor2: #fafaa3;
  --eventColor3: #e2f8ff;
  --eventColor4: #d1ffe6;
}

.calendar {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.timeline {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--numHours), var(--timeHeight));
}

.events {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--numHours), var(--timeHeight));
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: var(--calBgColor);
  width: 400px;
}

// Place on Timeline
.start-10 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.start-4 {
  grid-row-start: 4;
}

.start-1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.start-2 {
  grid-row-start: 6;
}

.end-12 {
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.end-6 {
  grid-row-end: 7;
}


.end-7 {
  grid-row-end: 8;
}

.end-10 {
  grid-row-end: 11;
}

// Event

.title {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

.event {
  border: 2px solid var(--eventBorderColor);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
}

.space,
.date {
  height: 100px
}

// Global / Etc

body {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}

.corp-fi {
  background: var(--eventColor1);
}

.ent-law {
  background: var(--eventColor2);
}

.writing {
  background: var(--eventColor3);
}

.securities {
  background: var(--eventColor4);
}

.date {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

.date-day {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.time-marker {
  border-top: dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="timeline">
    <div class="day-marker">2023-12-01</div>
    <div class="day-marker">2023-12-02</div>
    <div class="day-marker">2023-12-03</div>
    <div class="day-marker">2023-12-04</div>
    <div class="day-marker">2023-12-05</div>
    <div class="day-marker">2023-12-06</div>
    <div class="day-marker">2023-12-07</div>
    <div class="day-marker">2023-12-08</div>
    <div class="day-marker">2023-12-09</div>
    <div class="day-marker">2023-12-10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="events">
    <div class="event start-1 end-10 securities">
      <p class="title">Project A</p>
      <p class="time">1st to 10th</p>
    </div>
    <div class="event start-4 end-6 corp-fi">
      <p class="title">Project B</p>
      <p class="time">4th to 6th</p>
    </div>
    <div class="event start-1 end-7 ent-law">
      <p class="title">Project C</p>
      <p class="time">1st to 7th</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```